# Constant in-place array of strings and records in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe

Is something like this possible with Delphi? (with dynamic arrays of strings and records)

```
type
  TStringArray = array of String;
  TRecArray = array of TMyRecord;

procedure DoSomethingWithStrings(Strings : TStringArray);
procedure DoSomethingWithRecords(Records : TRecArray);
function BuildRecord(const Value : String) : TMyRecord;

DoSomethingWithStrings(['hello', 'world']);
DoSomethingWithRecords([BuildRecord('hello'), BuildRecord('world')]);
```

I know that it does not compile like that. Just wanted to ask if there's a trick to get something similar to that.

Comment: Be aware that writing `procedure DoSomethingWithStrings(Strings : TStringArray);` will create a temporary copy of the `TStringArray` parameter on the stack. You should better add a `const` here, i.e. write `procedure DoSomethingWithStrings(const Strings : TStringArray);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have to change the length of the arrays inside your `DoSomethingWith*` routines, I suggest using open arrays instead of dynamic ones, e.g. like this:

```
procedure DoSomethingWithStrings(const Strings: array of string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(Strings) to High(Strings) do
    Writeln(Strings[i]);
end;

procedure DoSomethingWithRecords(const Records: array of TMyRecord);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(Records) to High(Records) do
    Writeln(Records[i].s);
end;

procedure Test;
begin
  DoSomethingWithStrings(['hello', 'world']);
  DoSomethingWithRecords([BuildRecord('hello'), BuildRecord('world')]);
end;
```

Please note the `array of string` in the parameter list - not `TStringArray`! See the article ["Open array parameters and array of const"](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), especially the section about "Confusion", for more information.

Comment: +1 This is great. Thanks! I would have thought that `array of String` and `TStringArray` are type equivalent and therefore exchangeable but that does seem wrong.

Comment: That's one of Delphi's inconsistent areas. You can't write `set of TMyEnum` in a parameter list, you have to declare `TMyEnums = set of TMyEnum` and use that instead - same with pointers etc. But with arrays it's all different. :-)

Comment: The "incosistency" is just in the syntax because Delphi uses the same one with two different meaning based on context. "T: array of string" is a dynamic array. "procedure P(A: array of string)" is an open array parameter declaration - which is not a dynamic array, it takes any array of the given base type. If you want to pass explictly only dynamic arrays of a given type you would need a type declaration first and then a parameter of that type.

Comment: Probably "confusion" is the better expression: If you use Delphi some time you learn that `P(AMyEnums: set of TMyEnum)` doesn't work and that you'll have to declare a type explicitly. Now if you need to pass an array you will instinctively use an explicit type even if it's wrong.

Comment: IIRC that's because in Pascal two different var/param type declarations are not assignemnt compatible no matter how identical they are, thereby "A: array[0..1] of Bye; B: array[0..1] of Byte;" A and B are not assignment compatible, it works only if a type is declared first and then A and B declared of the same type. That's happens for parameters also. Open array parameters are a Delphi enhancement to Pascal rules, to allow for more flexibility in passing arrays to procedures, and IIRC they predates dynamic arrays