# Why is TArray<recordType> different from array of recordType?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a record type defined like:

```
type 
    TRecordType = record
        Field1: string;
        Field2: Variant;
    end;
```

And a function declaration using it:

```
function Function1(const Records: TArray<TRecordType>): TAnyOtherClass;
```

So far so good, but if the function is called like:

```
Function1([BuildRecord('string', value), BuildRecord('OtherString', otherValue)])
```

The compiler returns an error:

> [DCC Error] AnyUnit.pas(142): E2001 Ordinal type required

I have read some place a long time ago that Delphi's compiler handles generics in a kind of preprocessor with string replacements done before really compiling the code, so I was expecting `Function1` to become something like:

```
function Function1(const Records: array of TRecordType): TAnyOtherClass;
```

Because `TArray` is defined `TArray<T> = array of T;`.

I think it is not happening, because when I changed the function declaration to:

```
function Function1(const Records: array of TRecordType): TAnyOtherClass;
```

The code is compiled without errors or warnings.

There is an answer on [this question] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263305/constant-in-place-array-of-strings-and-records-in-delphi) that links to an article explaining the difference, but the link there is broken.

So my question is, what means `TArray<T>` if not `array of T`?

Comment: Open arrays are not the same as a typed array. [Open array parameters and array of const](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Comment: Delphi does not use a preprocessor for generics. Delphi generics are modelled on .Net generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Function1([BuildRecord('string', value), BuildRecord('OtherString', otherValue)])
```

The `[...]` syntax in your argument is what is known as an [open array constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions#Open_Array_Constructors). This documentation states, with my emphasis:

> Open array constructors allow you to construct arrays directly within function and procedure calls. They can be passed **only as** open array parameters or variant open array parameters.

Your function accepts a (generic) dynamic array type, which is different from an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters). Your function is declared as

```
function Function1(const Records: TArray<TRecordType>): TAnyOtherClass;
```

The parameter is a (generic) dynamic array type. An open array parameter would look like this:

```
function Function1(const Records: array of TRecordType): TAnyOtherClass;
```

I know this looks very like the declaration of a dynamic array, but it is not. In Delphi, `array of` has two distinct meanings:

- In the context of a parameter list, `array of` is used to declare an open array parameter.
- Elsewhere, `array of` defines a dynamic array type.

This *overloading* of the language syntax is a common cause for confusion.

So, because of all this, the compiler rejects your code, because you are attempting to use an open array constructor with a parameter that is not an open array.

My answer here goes into this issue in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14383278/505088

> I have read some place a long time ago that Delphi's compiler handles generics in a kind of preprocessor and some kind of string replace in code.

I think you are mis-remembering. What you are describing is more akin to C++ templates. Delphi generics are not handled by a preprocessor, not least because Delphi does not have a preprocessor.

Comment: So, it's a array's specific behavior, right? I am in doubt just on my declaration that the Delphi's compiler handles the generics on the preprocessor, this really proceeds?

Comment: @David, I think you need to explain the difference between: `array of` in `type definition` and in `parameter lists`. That seems to be the source of the confusing IMO. Right now you make a passing reference, but do not hit the issue on the head.

Comment: @jean It boils down to `array of` having two completely different meanings depending on the context. In a parmeter list, `array of` declares an **open array parameter**.  Elsewhere, `array of` declares a **type**.  Generics aren't really relevant here.  The same issue would arise if you used a type that was a non-generic dynamic array, also defined with `array of`. Generics are not handled by the preprocessor, not least because Delphi does not have a preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks guys, i think i understand now.

Comment: @Jean, Please read this article on the subject: ["Open array parameters and array of const"](http://www.praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-openarr.html). It will explain the difference between dynamic arrays and open array **parameters**.

Comment: Thanks @RudyVelthuis, i've read this article when others have commented on the question, it's very useful